# Try-catch issue with twitter api authentication

Tags: java, exception, twitter, twitter4j

I retrieve data from twitter. I ve stored some ids in a database and I am trying to retrieve informations with twitter API. I am using the following code:

```
if(cursor.hasNext()){
    try { 
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {

            final DBObject result = cursor.next();
            JSONObject features = new JSONObject();

            //System.out.println(result);
            Map<String, Object> value = (Map<String, Object>) result.get("user");
            boole.add((Boolean) value.get("default_profile")); 
            boole.add((Boolean) value.get("default_profile_image"));

            features.put("_id", value.get("id"));
     ...
     }
 catch (JSONException e) {
            System.err.println("JSONException while retrieving users from db: " + e);
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // do not throw if user has protected tweets, or if they deleted their account
            if (e.getStatusCode() == HttpResponseCode.UNAUTHORIZED || e.getStatusCode() == HttpResponseCode.NOT_FOUND) {


            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

I add twitter Exception since I cant retrieve data from some users due to authentication issues. However when my code reach  catch (TwitterException e) it automatically stop running. I want to continue to the next cursor (next database's id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have try catch block around your loop, so when exception is caught it falls out of the loop.

Placing try catch block inside while block will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `try-catch` block inside the `while` if you want to do that. Currently, once an exception is thrown in the `while`, it exits the `while` and goes to the `catch` block and the execution stops post that. If you move the `try` inside the `while`, the `while` will continue even after a exception is thrown and handled.

The loop and the try-catch should be structured like this.

```
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    try {
        // The code
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        // your code
    }
    catch (TwitterException e) {
        // your code
    }
}
```